# SQL Solve a Function with a While Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

Using SQL server, write a while loop to  calculate and print the functional value of f(x) = 3x&3 -2X^2 + 15 for all odd non negative integers <= 25. ( 1, 3, 5, …23,25).

This is what I have written out so far

[image: My Query]

And this is the result I get

[image: My Results]

So theoretically I should be getting 45,640 when `@x = 25`

What am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `power` function like the following

```
Declare @SUMSQUARE Integer, @x Integer
SET @X = 1

WHILE (@X <= 25)
BEGIN

SELECT @SUMSQUARE =  (3*power(@X,3))-(2*power(@X,2))+15
PRINT @SUMSQUARE
SET @X = @X + 2

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive cte (instead of using a `while` loop) to generate all the odd numbers <= 25 and then apply the function on those numbers.

```
with oddnums_cte as (select 1 num
                     union all
                     select num+2 from oddnums_cte where num < 25)
select num, (3*power(num,3))-(2*power(num,2))+15 as function_value
from oddnums_cte
```